# Looking for young adult series about a kid who escapes earth and goes starship racing

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

In the first book the kid escapes Earth and gets to a space station where, they have starship racing.  He starts out cleaning up and progresses to racing them.  I believe the author was towards the end of the alphabet, and that there may be six or more books in the series. read them used in the early 90's

Answer (score 7):

Roger Zelazny created the Alien Speedway series of novels in collaboration with other authors, which appeared between 1986-87:

Book 1 - "Clypsis" by Jeffrey A. Carver

Book 2 & 3 - "Pitfall" and "The Web" by Thomas Wylde

[http://www.amazon.com/Roger-Zelaznys-Alien-Speedway-ebook/dp/B0041OT67E/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041OT67E)

Comment: thats it thanks os much